# Backbone.js Event Aggregator issues

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I ended up in a situation where I bind an event with the same name more than once on the event aggregatior and ends up triggering all the events[with the same name] at the same time.I cant show my entire code here as its quite a lot but I have managed to replicate the issue with few lines of code.

```
var vent = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);

vent.bind("editMedication", function(){//first time
    console.log('editMedication 1');
});

vent.bind("editMedication", function(){//second time
    console.log('editMedication 2');
});

vent.bind("editMedication", function(){//third time
    console.log('editMedication 3');
});

vent.bind("editMedication", function(){//fourth time
    console.log('editMedication 4');
});

vent.trigger("editMedication"); // this triggers all the events with the name 'editMedication'
```

Is it possible to clear all the events I binded earlier and keep the last entry?

Comment: Have you thought about passing arguments to your event handler when the event is triggered?

Comment: @fbynite sorry didnt get that, how will that stop other events from triggering?

Comment: It won't. I wasn't very clear, but you could bind one `editMedication` event, and pass arguments to it. For example, `vent.trigger('editMedication',1)`.

Answer (score 1):

As seen in [the docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-off), before each new bind, unbind the event:

```
vent.unbind("editMedication");
```